# number of clients queued by server and if a client is queued or not

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, nio, serversocket

How to check if a client is backlogged by server ? and check how many clients are backlogged?

i have a server with SocketServer initialized and i have a client trying to connect.
the server side code would be

```
  ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(9000,1);
  Socket so=sock.accept();
```

and the client side will be

```
  Socket soc = new Socket("localhost",9000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by backlogged?

Comment: Are you useing NIO2 to handle the sockets efficiently on your server side?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII  NIO2? NO i dint. i also have no clear idea on what they are.

Comment: @peter.petrov  requested maximum length of the queue of incoming connections. i the 1 i passed as parameter to serversocket

Comment: Use of the Java "Network IO 2" provides a more efficient means to produce a server ... which can keep you from having to have a separate process (thread) for each socket you serve.  If you are having capacity problems on your server side, you should look into NIO2 (part of standard Java 7)

Comment: OK, it is still not clear what you mean by 'how many clients are backlogged'. You want to check how many there're currently in the queue or how many free positions are there in the queue?

Comment: @peter.petrov  yup that's exactly what i want to do. and if a client is  in queue or not.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII I am just trying basic sockets. i dint yet study about threads, thanks for advice.

Comment: @peter.petrov u know how to do? at least the intuitive idea

Comment: @ErstwhileIII Your question is pointless. NIO2 isn't relevant to the answer.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. I do ask questions sometimes. Here is a "could" from me to your "should": you could have said the same thing with a different "tone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to check if a client is backlogged by server?

With a Selector.

> and check how many clients are backlogged?

With Selector.selectedKeySet().size().

This assumes you are only selecting for OP_ACCEPT of course.